# Ошибка при попытке запуска

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

После того как начал использовать Socket в приложении, приложение перестало запускаться (иногда помогает перезагрузка), выдает ошибку в отладчике сразу после нажатия run

> Ошибка при попытке запуска проекта: Не удается запустить программу "F:\Microsoft Visual Studio 2012\ASAM\ASAM\bin\Debug\ASAM.exe". 
>   The address is not valid for this context.

остальные проекты (без Socket) запускаются успешно.

**В чем может быть проблема, если программа точно не успевает проинициализировать переменные с типами IPEndPoint, Socket, TcpListener**

Comment: По слухам, может быть вызвано установленным сниффером - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27195176/1988244

Comment: Нет такого агента, хотя как x86 запускается без проблем

Answer (score 1):

Нашел эту гадость AdguardSvc.exe, кому небудь пригодиться

Comment: А что это было? Вирус?